# Speech recognition for android

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I want to **speech recognition for burmese language.**

I refer following links :

- http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/
- http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/
- http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

but not getting any success,

Is there any other way like record and convert speech to text or after record compare with audio file. please help me and give me any solution.

Comment: Hi for voice recognition @speech recognition try to follow the following link 1) http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html 2)http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/  This two tutorial will give you some idea how you can convert speech to text in android.

Answer (score 5):

As Burmese isn't currently a supported language for Android's built-in cloud-based speech recognition, PocketSphinx may be your best bet. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is an existing language model for Burmese, so you will have to build a custom Burmese language model, which requires a large corpus of text and some linguistic expertise.

[CMUSphinx - Building Language Model](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm)

...additionally, you'll need to train an acoustic model, which requires a lot of recorded audio. For general dictation (i.e., general purpose speech-to-text that can be used by many different people), the Sphinx project folks recommend you have 50 hours of recordings of 200 different speakers.

[CMUSphinx - Training Acoustic Model For CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam)

I've had a good experience using PocketSphinx on Android, but only for a small language model (i.e., a command-and-control type of application), and only in English. Doing so for Burmese is possible, but will take a lot of work to build and train the models mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

you can find several tutorials at
http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

you can try the code found here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html

Comment: The link is not available. Could you please update it